# Let $M$ be a free $R$-module, and let it have an infinite basis. Then all bases of $M$ have the same cardinality

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

I need to prove the following:

> Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring (according to Lang, Bourbaki etc., so, with $1$). Let $M$ be a free $R$-module, and let $A$ be one of it's bases. If $|\mathbb{N}| \leq |A|$, then all bases of $M$ have the same cardinality.

Any ideas on how to prove it? 
Obviously, every element of $A$ is a unique finite sum of elements of $B$, and vice versa.

Comment: The ring $R$ is commutative with unity? 

In an affirmative case, you may use tensor products.

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba no, it's an arbitrary ring (with $1$), not necessarily commutative.

Comment: in this case I don't know how to proceed, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a free module has an infinite basis, it is not finitely generated; so any two bases must be infinite.

Suppose $B$ and $C$ are bases. For each $b\in B$, there is a finite subset $C(b)$ of $C$ such that $b$ is a linear combination of the elements in $C(b)$. Thus we have a map $b\mapsto C(b)$; then $|B|\ge|\{C(b):b\in B\}|$. Since each $C(b)$ is finite, we have
$$
\Bigl|\bigcup_{b\in B}C(b)\Bigr|\le \aleph_0|B|=|B|
$$
Now, prove that
$$
\bigcup_{b\in B}C(b)=C
$$
By symmetry, $|B|\le|C|$.

Comment: Can you help on understanding why $\bigcup_{b \in B} C(b) = C$? I've been thinking about it for a while, but to no avail. Obviously, $\bigcup_{b \in B} C(b) \subseteq C$, so we assume there is $b' \in B \setminus \bigcup_{b \in B} C(b)$ and should come to a contradiction.

Comment: @Jxt921 Let $C'=\bigcup_{b\in B}C(b)$. Note that every element of $B$ is a linear combination of elements of $C'$. Then an element in $C\setminus C'$ is a linear combination of elements of $C'$.